# lining up fieldset tags horizontally in css3

Tags: css, fieldset

I cannot get these two fieldsets to line up horizontally.I've tried every variation of float and display I could think of. I currently do not have these elements in a div although I tried that too. Do they have to be in a div?

```
<fieldset class="bio1">
  <legend>Name</legend>
  <p>President</p><br/>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="bioimage">
   <legend>Picture</legend>
   <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/BioImages/bio.jpg" />
 </fieldset>
```

Comment: What do you mean by line up horizontally? I don't think you can make them both have the same height using just CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A matter of CSS (not especially CSS3).
Set both of them (fieldsets css) to

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top; /* enter your desired option */
```

Comment: thanks, the bio1 fieldset needs the display:inline setting not block. Got it working