# How to make two fieldset horizontally?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fieldset

I have a form with two fieldset elements

```
<form>
   <fieldset>
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

I need to make to be horizontally?

Comment: Maybe use a library. like aui:column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lining up fieldset tags horizontally in css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299068/lining-up-fieldset-tags-horizontally-in-css3)

Answer (score 2):

Just float them and add a width.

```
fieldset {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put them in a row fluid span6.  You can do some other things, but the well will cause issues with row.

```
<form class="row-fluid well">
    <fieldset class='span6'>
      <legend>Legend 1</legend>
      <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="option1"/> Option1
      </label>    
        <label class="radio">
         <input type="radio" name="option2"/> Option2
      </label> 
    </fieldset>    

    <fieldset class='span6'>
       <legend>Legend 2</legend>
       <select>
           <option> option1 </option>
        </select>    
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by add to the mother:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

and add to the fieldset:

```
display: block; float: left;
```

See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/JXf8g/25/